# matrix/data frame of special characters

Tags: r, character, symbols

I am trying to construct an R matrix/data frame with special characters in it. For example, one cell would contain `"2\u00B15\u00B3"` (i.e. "2±5³").

I need to have Latin lowercase alphabets in the superscript, instead of the number superscript and I was only able to find the [Unicode for few alphabets as superscripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).

I am familiar with all the special symbols within the plot functions (e.g. for labeling axis, titles etc.) but I need the "superscripting" within a matrix.

**EDIT:** I wanted to do something like this, with only one exception, instead of the 3 in the supescript in `3.5\u00B12\u00B3`, I want to have latin alphabets.

```
require(rtf)
rtf<-RTF("./Doc/test_addTable.doc",width=8.5,height=11,font.size=10,omi=c(1,1,1,1))

A = data.frame(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4),
Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9),
Petal.Length = c(1.4,  1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2,0.2,0.2, 0.4))

A[1,2] = "3.5\u00B12\u00B3"

addTable(rtf,A,font.size=10,row.names=FALSE,NA.string="-",col.widths=rep(1,4))

done(rtf)
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The phrase "within a matrix" is a bit unclear. Can you be more specific about what requirements are being expected for this "matrix"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R there is a system that is like mini-LaTeX but is called "plotmath". It is driven off expression objects and is invoked when an expression hits a text=plotting value. It doesn't really make much sense to have such a matrix if you are not going to plot it, so I will illustrate how to raise character values as superscripts.

```
?plotmath
plot(1,1)
text( x=c(.8), y=c(1.2), substitute( 2%+-%5^x, list(x="A") ))
```

That is a bit more complicate than might be needed for a single instance but that is designed to increase generality. You could also do:

```
text( x=c(.8), y=c(.8), expression(2%+-%5^B) )
```

If you just want a matrix of plotmath  (in character form):

```
mat <- matrix( c( '2%+-%5^B' , '2%+-%5^C',
                  '2%+-%5^D' , '2%+-%5^B'), 2, 2)
mat
```

You cannot (or at least I cannot) really construct a true R expression object as a matrix:

```
 mat <- matrix( expression(2%+-%5^B , 2%+-%5^C,
                   2%+-%5^D , 2%+-%5^B), 2, 2)
     mat
#expression(2 %+-% 5^B, 2 %+-% 5^C, 2 %+-% 5^D, 2 %+-% 5^B)
> str(mat)
length 4 expression(2 %+-% 5^B, 2 %+-% 5^C, 2 %+-% 5^D) ...
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 2
> mat[1,1]
Error in mat[1, 1] : matrix subscripting not handled for this type
> mat[1]
expression(2 %+-% 5^B)
> mat[2]
expression(2 %+-% 5^C)
> mat[3]
expression(2 %+-% 5^D)
```

I did manage to get the matrix function to attach dimensions to an expression object but neither `print` nor `[` would honor that dimension. I remain unclear as to the goal. In the `rtf` package I see the addTable method and I'm wondering if you you really want to have an object that will be printed by an rtf-aware application in "matrix" or tabular form?

Hah.... I think I have it:

```
 mat <- matrix( c( '2\\+/-5 {\\up3B}' , '2%+-%5 \\up5C',
                   '2%+-%5\\up3B' , '2%+-%5\\up4H'), 2, 2)
 mat
#     [,1]               [,2]          
#[1,] "2\\+/-5 {\\up3B}" "2%+-%5\\up3B"
#[2,] "2%+-%5 \\up5C"    "2%+-%5\\up4H"
 rtf<-RTF("test_addTable.doc",width=8.5,height=11,
                  font.size=10,omi=c(1,1,1,1))
 addTable(rtf, mat)
 done(rtf)
```

[image]

Furthermore I think I fingered out the plusminus sign. Try:

```
 "2\\u177BD5 {\\up3B}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am aware of "plotmath" and the fact that you can write Latex-like expression (I am also familiar with knitr etc.). I need to construct a matrix of characters(no plotting) where the cells are of the form "a%+-%b^c" (without the use of knitr because I want to export it to a .rtf file using the rtf package).  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: So it is more a question of what sort of character argument will get interpreted by the rtf parser as a superscript? According to http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm it might be `\upN`. What sort of test of success do you propose? (And all this added information _should_ go into editing your original question. It still doesn't really have enough code to qualify as a real SO question.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the 1st time I am asking here; I apologize if I was adding my comments in the wrong area. I appreciate your help!

Comment: So plotmath was entirely useless.